# Why does performing a map on an iterator not cause it to be modified?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, iterator

```
> val textIt = text.split("\\s").iterator
> val upperIt = textIt.map(_.toUpperCase)
> textIt
res14: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator
```

Why is `textIt` not empty? I would expect it to become an empty iterator due to `map` iterating over them. What is actually happening under the hood?

Comment: What is ``it``? Should it not read: ``val upperIt = textIt.map(_.toUpperCase)`` instead?

Comment: I think that was a typing mistake. Just assume it to be `textIt`.

Comment: This trouble you are having reasoning about mutable data structures is quite valid, you should just avoid them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `Iterator.map` returns new `Iterator` object without traversing over it:

```
def map[B](f: A => B): Iterator[B] = new AbstractIterator[B] {
  def hasNext = self.hasNext
  def next() = f(self.next())
}
```

Iterating over `textIt` is performed when you iterate over `upperIt`.

Comment: Are you saying that in this case map traverses over a copy of `textIt` instead of the real `textIt`?